# What's Rails 3 got that Rails 2 ain't got? (And should I learn it?)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

## Background

I've written several production apps using Rails 2. I've gotten comfortable with it. I kind of have my Rails 2 routine down.

However, now I face a dilemma.

I have two new apps to write immediately.

Rails 3 has been out for a while now, and I wonder if it's time to get a book, invest some weekends and evenings, and start coding these and any further apps using Rails 3.

The things I write are usually stuff like "take our equipment inventory that's in MS Access and make a Web app of it," or "write an app that lets the secretaries post PDFs to our website and attach notations to them." (Those are made-up examples to give you an idea -- not the actual apps I'm working on or have ever worked on.)

#### Side note

On a personal level, I do understand the value of learning for its own sake and I am genuinely *curious* and *interested* in learning Rails 3. But I also have to respect time and energy limitations. I'm curious and interested in a lot of things. So I have to choose carefully.

## Main question

What features / capabilities / improvements does Rails 3 have that might make the investment of time and risk worthwhile?

Or to put it another way, if I invest a week or two on Rails 3 tutorials, will it pay off in huge times savings later because Rails 3 development is way more efficient?

### Other question

Is there a major downside to just sticking with Rails 2 for another few years or another four or five apps? Some looming danger I should be aware of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a list of the most major changes [at the Rails weblog](http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2010/8/29/rails-3-0-it-s-done), and others [in the official Rails documentation](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/3_0_release_notes.html). A lot of the changes involve cleaner syntax (some of the  bigger ones being unobtrusive javascript and new routes syntax) and simpler ways to do common things (ActionMailer, chainable AREL).

Answer (score 3):

Here is my take on it:

1. New plugins and gems will be developed for Rails 3.x, not Rails 2. And what speeds ups development most, are solutions supplied and maintained by a community.
2. Bundler. Although it can be used with 2.x, I admit.
3. Engines! It's not well docummented at the moment, and maybe a bit buggy, but I feel it will be an enabler for nice things.
4. Finally, and most important - you'll wake up one day, as a master in Rails 2.x, when a situation will require from you being a moderate Rails 3x framework user. That's inevitable imho.

And a transition to Rails 3 will not be as near as painfull where we had only beta / release candidates. So I encourage you to go for Rails 3.